# angularjs: how to refresh HTML from aggregated scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

3 selects with ng-model bound to search.accident.XXXXX.id controller scope variable are used to search from a data structure.
While the first HTML snippet works hassle-free, the second gets stuck whatever the variable is changed.
I think of a sort of 'update' issue: do I need to hint angularjs about the aggregate nature of the data structure? How?

Working snippet as follows:

```
<h2>
    «&nbsp;{{search.accident.symptom.id}}&nbsp;»
    observé(es) sur «&nbsp;{{search.accident.organ.id}}&nbsp;» 
    à l'étape «&nbsp;{{search.accident.stage.id}}&nbsp;»
</h2>
```

Non working snippet as follows:

```
<h2>
    «&nbsp;{{search.accident.symptom.displayName}}&nbsp;»
    observé(es) sur «&nbsp;{{search.accident.organ.displayName}}&nbsp;» 
    à l'étape «&nbsp;{{search.accident.stage.displayName}}&nbsp;»
</h2>
```

[edit]

Here is the select code:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 40%">
                    Stade<br>
                    de la plante<br>
                    <select 
                        ng-options="s.id as s.displayName for s in stages" 
                        ng-model="search.accident.stage.id">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    Organe<br>
                    concerné<br>
                    <select
                        ng-options="o.id as o.displayName for o in organs | filter:accidentsSearch(search.accident.stage, null, null, accidentsDiagnosticsMenu)" 
                        ng-model="search.accident.organ.id">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Symptôme<br>
                    observé<br>
                    <select
                        ng-options="s.id as s.displayName for s in symptoms | filter:accidentsSearch(search.accident.stage, search.accident.organ, null, accidentsDiagnosticsMenu)" 
                        ng-model="search.accident.symptom.id">
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: If you really only bind the xxx.id to your scope variable, there really is no reason why your xxx.name should update. You should probably bind your xxx item. Please share some of your code so that we can take a look at it and suggest a solution.

Comment: @PSL the second snippet does not update when a different value is selected by the user in the related FORM SELECT tag. I added the select code.

Comment: @Sycomor is it possible to ng-model the two members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select ng-options="s.id as s.displayName for s in stages" 
                    ng-model="search.accident.stage.id">
</select>
```

What the above means is: display a select box displaying the displayName of the stages. Whenever a selection is made, update the field `search.accident.stage.id` with the `id` of the selected stage.

So, whenever a selection is changed, the search.accident.stage is left unmodified, except for its ID. What you want is

```
<select ng-options="s as s.displayName for s in stages" 
                    ng-model="search.accident.stage">
</select>
```

which means: display a select box displaying the displayName of the stages. Whenever a selection is made, update the field `search.accident.stage` with the selected stage.

Comment: Wow, you made my day! :-) @JB Nizet

Comment: I have one more issue related to this selectors, and I just created a new question for it, you might be interested in answering : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194502/angularjs-whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-3-criteria-selection-provided-the-crit?noredirect=1#comment41074398_26194502

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the view code. Just change your selects to something like :

```
<select 
    ng-options="s.displayName for s in stages" 
    ng-model="search.accident.stage">
</select>
```

if the select clause is omitted in `ng-options`, the binding defaults to the object itself (your `s`), so you are stating that the s being selected (with s.displayName as the select label) will be stored in your search.accident.stage. You then just have to retrieve its fields wherever you want to display them.