# angularjs: what's the best way to make a 3-criteria selection, provided the criteria are linked together?

Tags: angularjs

I have this data structure which links 3 criteria:

```
stages[stageid] -> organs[organid] -> symptoms[symptomid]
```

With the kind of join as follows:

stages[stageid] contains possible organic while organs[organid] contains possible symptoms.

I want to create an HTML form made of 3 selects which enables the user to select the observation he wants.

My current implementation (I'm not fan of) is based on filters, and has one flaw: I'm am not able to preselect default value picked when the user select a new value on the "linked" select.

Here is my code for reference:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 40%">
                    Stade<br>
                    de la plante<br>
                    <select 
                        ng-options="s as s.displayName for s in stages" 
                        ng-model="search.accident.stage">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    Organe<br>
                    concerné<br>
                    <select
                        ng-options="o as o.displayName for o in organs | filter:accidentsSearch(search.accident.stage, null, null, accidentsDiagnosticsMenu)" 
                        ng-model="search.accident.organ">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Symptôme<br>
                    observé<br>
                    <select
                        ng-options="s as s.displayName for s in symptoms | filter:accidentsSearch(search.accident.stage, search.accident.organ, null, accidentsDiagnosticsMenu)" 
                        ng-model="search.accident.symptom">
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

[edit]

Added the filter code:

```
$scope.accidentsSearch = function( stage, organ, symptom, accidentsDiagnosticsMenu ) {
    console.log("------>>> filter organs for criteria: "+stage.id+", "+(organ?organ.id:"null")+", "+(symptom?symptom.id:"null"));

    if (organ==null && symptom ==null) {
        console.log("------>filter organs for criteria stage: "+stage.displayName+", "+organ+", "+symptom);
        return function( organToCheck ) {
            if (!accidentsDiagnosticsMenu) return false;    // not yet prepared

            var keep = accidentsDiagnosticsMenu[stage.id][organToCheck.id];
            //console.log("Exploring pruned with "+stage.displayName+": "+JSON.stringify(pruned));
            if (keep) {
                //console.log("Checking organs "+o+"=="+organToCheck+" for stage "+ stage.displayName+ ", so keep = "+keep);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        };
    }
    else
    if (symptom == null) {
        //console.log("------>filter for criteria stage/organ : "+stage.displayName+", "+organ.displayName+", "+symptom);
        return function(symptomToCheck ) {
            if (!accidentsDiagnosticsMenu) return false;    // not yet prepared

            var keep = accidentsDiagnosticsMenu[stage.id][organ.id][symptomToCheck.id];
            //console.log("---- Exploring pruned with "+stage.id+", "+organ.id+": "+JSON.stringify(accidentsDiagnosticsMenu[stage.id][organ.id]));
            if (keep) {
                //console.log("Checking symptom "+symptomToCheck.id+" for stage "+ stage.id+" and organ "+organ.id+ ", so keep = "+keep);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        };
    }
    else {
        //console.log("------>filter for criteria "+stage.displayName+", "+organ.displayName+", "+symptom.displayName);
        return function( diag ) {
            var keep = 
                (diag.stageId   == stage.id)    // same stage?
            &&  (diag.organId   == organ.id)    // same organs?
            &&  (diag.symptomId == symptom.id); // same symptoms?
            //if (keep) console.log((keep?"Keep":"Drop")+" "+diag);
            return keep;
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: I had provided an answer earlier.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413071/how-to-handle-cascading-chained-dropdowns-using-multiple-ng-options/25415189#25415189 WHich is probably similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: @PSL nope, it's linked to the same piece of code, but the issue is different and related to the fact that each select is linked to the others, and I need to update the values of the linked select depending on the previous ones.

Comment: Using filter is probably a bad idea for achieving this. You should remember they run every digest cycle unwantedly (in your case)... And what you really need is `ng-change` as in @JBNizet's answer and my posted link.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `ng-change` attribute on select to call a scope function every time the selection changes. The function can simply create the array for the linked select box, and populate the linked select box ngModel with a default value.

For example:

```
<select ng-options="s as s.displayName for s in stages" 
        ng-model="search.accident.stage"
        ng-change="createOrgansAndSelectDefaultOrganForStage(search.accident.stage)">
</select>
```

Another way is to use `$scope.$watch('search.accident.stage', callback)` to execute the callback function every time `search.accident.stage` changes, but this is dirtier, and harder to test.

Comment: I agree with `ng-change` too, but i wouldn't suggest the creation of watch at all, it bad IMHO especially if you are doing it in a controller. I had a similar example posted as comment, but seems like today OP is on a roll to get the work done.. :)

Comment: Agreed that $watch is not the best solution. I mentioned it for completeness.

Comment: I implmented a ng-change scope function. My issue actually is that I don't understand why the default value in the select if not sect accordingly to the ng-model scope variable.